# Python Tkinter on Debian Beaglebone: lost font styling when changed directory name

Tags: python, tkinter, beagleboneblack

I have installed non-system fonts onto BeagleBone Black (Debian Jessie) and have been using them in a GUI created using python 2.7 script via Tkinter and tkFont. When I changed the name of the directory my file was stored in, these fonts stopped appearing in my python script GUI!

I installed the fonts into /usr/shared/fonts and they are still there, of course, but somehow I lost the connection to the fonts from my script.

I ran `fc-cache -fv` and rebooted. I ran a short script with

```
list( tkFont.families() )
```

in it, any the fonts I want to use appear in the list.

Still displaying system font in the GUI.

How can it be? Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import Queue

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

try:
    import alsaaudio as aa
    import audioop
    import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
    debug = False
except ImportError:
    # To enable simple testing on systems without alsa/gpio
    import mock

    aa = mock.MagicMock()
    aa.PCM().read.return_value = (1, '')

    audioop = mock.MagicMock()
    audioop.max.return_value = 5000

    GPIO = mock.MagicMock()

    import random
    GPIO.input.side_effect = lambda *a: random.randint(0, 5000) == 0

    debug = True

# layout ########################################################

BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#000000'

TEXTBOX_WIDTH = 1920

# vertical alignment of text in percentages from top

V_ALIGN_L1 = .16
V_ALIGN_L2 = .28
V_ALIGN_HEADER = .52
V_ALIGN_SCORE = .68
V_ALIGN_TILT = .50
V_ALIGN_AGAIN = .68

# type ##########################################################

TYPEFACE_L1 = 'Avenir Next Demi Bold'
TYPEFACE_L2 = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_HEADER = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_SCORE = 'Avenir Next Demi Bold'
TYPEFACE_TILT = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_AGAIN = 'Avenir Next Bold'

WEIGHT_L1 = tkFont.NORMAL
WEIGHT_L2 = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_HEADER = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_SCORE = tkFont.NORMAL
WEIGHT_TILT = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_AGAIN = tkFont.BOLD

FONT_SIZE_L1 = 56
FONT_SIZE_L2 = 56
FONT_SIZE_HEADER = 76
FONT_SIZE_SCORE = 168
FONT_SIZE_TILT = 114
FONT_SIZE_AGAIN = 76

LINE_HEIGHT_L1 = -5
LINE_HEIGHT_L2 = -5
LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER = -10
LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE = -20
LINE_HEIGHT_TILT = -20
LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN = -1

TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT = '#FFFFFF'
TEXT_COLOR_BODY = '#92C73D'

# text ###########################################################

L1 = 'Try to beat your own score.'
L2 = 'The lowest score wins!'
HEADER_MESSAGE = 'Your Score:'
TILT_MESSAGE = 'Too loud!'
TRY_AGAIN = 'Start again!'

# audio collection configuration ##################################

BUTTON_PIN = 'P8_12'

DEVICE = 'hw:1'  # hardware sound card index
CHANNELS = 2
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100  # Hz
PERIOD = 256  # Frames
FORMAT = aa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE  # Sound format

NOISE_THRESHOLD = 0  # to eliminate small noises, scale of 0 - 7
TILT_THRESHOLD = 100.0 # upper limit of score before tilt state
SCALAR = 4680 # normalizes score, found by trial and error
UPDATE_TIME = 100 # ms

# start script ###################################################

class Display(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, queue, stop_event):
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue
        self.stop_event = stop_event
        self.tilt_event = threading.Event()

        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        parent.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            parent.winfo_screenwidth(), parent.winfo_screenheight()))
        parent.overrideredirect(1)

        parent.title(TITLE)
        parent.configure(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        self.create_text()
        self.process_queue()

        self.audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.setup_audio)
        self.audio_thread.start()

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        instance.stop_event.set()

    def create_text(self):
        message_kwargs = dict(
            bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            width=TEXTBOX_WIDTH,
            justify='c',
        )

        self.message_L1 = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=L1,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_L1, WEIGHT_L1),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_L1,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_L2 = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=L2,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_L2, WEIGHT_L2),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_L2,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_score_header = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=HEADER_MESSAGE,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
            font=(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_HEADER, WEIGHT_HEADER),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER,
            **message_kwargs)
        self.message_score = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text='0.0',
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=(TYPEFACE_SCORE, FONT_SIZE_SCORE, WEIGHT_SCORE),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_L1.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_L1, anchor='c')
        self.message_L2.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_L2, anchor='c')
        self.message_score_header.place(relx=V_ALIGN_HEADER, rely=.5, anchor='c')
        self.message_score.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_SCORE, anchor='c')

    def process_queue(self):
        text = None
        while not self.queue.empty():
            text = self.queue.get_nowait()

        if text:
            self.message_score_header.configure(text=HEADER_MESSAGE)
            self.message_score.configure(text=text)
        elif self.tilt_event.is_set():
            self.message_L1.configure(text="")
            self.message_L2.configure(text="")
            self.message_score_header.configure(text=TILT_MESSAGE, fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT, font=(TYPEFACE_TILT, FONT_SIZE_TILT, WEIGHT_TILT), pady=LINE_HEIGHT_TILT)
            self.message_score.configure(text=TRY_AGAIN, fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY, font=(TYPEFACE_AGAIN, FONT_SIZE_AGAIN, WEIGHT_AGAIN), pady=LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN)
            self.message_score.place(relx=.75, rely=V_ALIGN_AGAIN, anchor='c')

        self.parent.after(UPDATE_TIME, self.process_queue)

    def setup_audio(self):
        data_in = aa.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NONBLOCK, DEVICE)
        data_in.setchannels(2)
        data_in.setrate(SAMPLE_RATE)
        data_in.setformat(FORMAT)

        data_in.setperiodsize(PERIOD)

        score = 0
        running = False

        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            # Sleep a very short time to prevent the thread from locking up
            time.sleep(0.001)

            if GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN):
                self.tilt_event.clear()
                score = 0
                if not running:
                    self.message_L1.configure(text=L1)
                    self.message_L2.configure(text=L2)
                    self.message_score_header.configure(text=HEADER_MESSAGE, fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY, font=(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_HEADER, WEIGHT_HEADER), pady=LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER)
                    self.message_score.configure(text='0.0', fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT, font=(TYPEFACE_SCORE, FONT_SIZE_SCORE, WEIGHT_SCORE), pady=LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE)
                    self.message_score.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_SCORE, anchor='c')

                    running = True
                self.queue.put('0.0')
            elif not running:
                # Not running yet, keep waiting
                continue

            # Read data from device
            l, data = data_in.read()
            if l and not self.tilt_event.is_set():
                # catch frame error
                try:
                    max = audioop.max(data, CHANNELS)
                    scaled_max = max // SCALAR

                    if scaled_max <= NOISE_THRESHOLD:
                        # Too quiet, ignore
                        continue

                    score += scaled_max / 10.0

                    if score > TILT_THRESHOLD:
                        self.tilt_event.set()
                        running = False
                    else:
                        self.queue.put(str(score))

                except audioop.error, e:
                    if e.message != "not a whole number of frames":
                        raise e


def main():
    GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    window = None

    try:
        root = tk.Tk()
        queue = Queue.Queue()
        window = Display(root, queue, stop_event)

        # Force the window to the foreground
        root.attributes('-topmost', True)
        if debug:
            root.maxsize(1920, 1200)

        root.mainloop()
    finally:
        stop_event.set()
        if window:
            window.audio_thread.join()
        del window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are no error messages when I run the script.

**EDIT:** It is also worth mentioning that the font size and weight are working, just not the typeface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `Font()` construct:

```
self.message_score.configure(
    text=TRY_AGAIN,
    fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
    font=(TYPEFACE_AGAIN, FONT_SIZE_AGAIN, WEIGHT_AGAIN),
    pady=LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN)
```

Instead it probably be:

```
self.message_score.configure(
    text=TRY_AGAIN,
    fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
    font=tkFont.Font(TYPEFACE_AGAIN, FONT_SIZE_AGAIN, WEIGHT_AGAIN),
    pady=LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN)
```

The full version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import Queue

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

try:
    import alsaaudio as aa
    import audioop
    import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
    debug = False
except ImportError:
    # To enable simple testing on systems without alsa/gpio
    import mock

    aa = mock.MagicMock()
    aa.PCM().read.return_value = (1, '')

    audioop = mock.MagicMock()
    audioop.max.return_value = 5000

    GPIO = mock.MagicMock()

    import random
    GPIO.input.side_effect = lambda *a: random.randint(0, 5000) == 0

    debug = True

# layout ########################################################

BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#000000'

TEXTBOX_WIDTH = 1920

# vertical alignment of text in percentages from top

V_ALIGN_L1 = .16
V_ALIGN_L2 = .28
V_ALIGN_HEADER = .52
V_ALIGN_SCORE = .68
V_ALIGN_TILT = .50
V_ALIGN_AGAIN = .68

# type ##########################################################

TYPEFACE_L1 = 'Avenir Next Demi Bold'
TYPEFACE_L2 = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_HEADER = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_SCORE = 'Avenir Next Demi Bold'
TYPEFACE_TILT = 'Avenir Next Bold'
TYPEFACE_AGAIN = 'Avenir Next Bold'

WEIGHT_L1 = tkFont.NORMAL
WEIGHT_L2 = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_HEADER = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_SCORE = tkFont.NORMAL
WEIGHT_TILT = tkFont.BOLD
WEIGHT_AGAIN = tkFont.BOLD

FONT_SIZE_L1 = 56
FONT_SIZE_L2 = 56
FONT_SIZE_HEADER = 76
FONT_SIZE_SCORE = 168
FONT_SIZE_TILT = 114
FONT_SIZE_AGAIN = 76

LINE_HEIGHT_L1 = -5
LINE_HEIGHT_L2 = -5
LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER = -10
LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE = -20
LINE_HEIGHT_TILT = -20
LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN = -1

TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT = '#FFFFFF'
TEXT_COLOR_BODY = '#92C73D'

# text ###########################################################

L1 = 'Try to beat your own score.'
L2 = 'The lowest score wins!'
HEADER_MESSAGE = 'Your Score:'
TILT_MESSAGE = 'Too loud!'
TRY_AGAIN = 'Start again!'

# audio collection configuration ##################################

BUTTON_PIN = 'P8_12'

DEVICE = 'hw:1'  # hardware sound card index
CHANNELS = 2
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100  # Hz
PERIOD = 256  # Frames
FORMAT = aa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE  # Sound format

NOISE_THRESHOLD = 0  # to eliminate small noises, scale of 0 - 7
TILT_THRESHOLD = 100.0 # upper limit of score before tilt state
SCALAR = 4680 # normalizes score, found by trial and error
UPDATE_TIME = 100 # ms

# start script ###################################################

class Display(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, queue, stop_event):
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue
        self.stop_event = stop_event
        self.tilt_event = threading.Event()

        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        parent.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            parent.winfo_screenwidth(), parent.winfo_screenheight()))
        parent.overrideredirect(1)

        parent.title(TITLE)
        parent.configure(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        self.create_text()
        self.process_queue()

        self.audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.setup_audio)
        self.audio_thread.start()

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        instance.stop_event.set()

    def create_text(self):
        message_kwargs = dict(
            bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            width=TEXTBOX_WIDTH,
            justify='c',
        )

        self.message_L1 = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=L1,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=tkFont.Font(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_L1, WEIGHT_L1),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_L1,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_L2 = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=L2,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=tkFont.Font(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_L2, WEIGHT_L2),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_L2,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_score_header = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text=HEADER_MESSAGE,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
            font=tkFont.Font(TYPEFACE_HEADER, FONT_SIZE_HEADER, WEIGHT_HEADER),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER,
            **message_kwargs)
        self.message_score = tk.Message(
            self.parent,
            text='0.0',
            fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
            font=tkFont.Font(TYPEFACE_SCORE, FONT_SIZE_SCORE, WEIGHT_SCORE),
            pady=LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE,
            **message_kwargs)

        self.message_L1.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_L1, anchor='c')
        self.message_L2.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_L2, anchor='c')
        self.message_score_header.place(relx=V_ALIGN_HEADER, rely=.5, anchor='c')
        self.message_score.place(relx=.5, rely=V_ALIGN_SCORE, anchor='c')

    def process_queue(self):
        text = None
        while not self.queue.empty():
            text = self.queue.get_nowait()

        if text:
            self.message_score_header.configure(text=HEADER_MESSAGE)
            self.message_score.configure(text=text)
        elif self.tilt_event.is_set():
            self.message_L1.configure(text="")
            self.message_L2.configure(text="")
            self.message_score_header.configure(
                text=TILT_MESSAGE,
                fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
                font=tkFont.Font(
                    TYPEFACE_TILT,
                    FONT_SIZE_TILT,
                    WEIGHT_TILT,
                ),
                pady=LINE_HEIGHT_TILT)
            self.message_score.configure(
                text=TRY_AGAIN,
                fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
                font=tkFont.Font(
                    TYPEFACE_AGAIN,
                    FONT_SIZE_AGAIN,
                    WEIGHT_AGAIN,
                ),
                pady=LINE_HEIGHT_AGAIN)
            self.message_score.place(relx=.75, rely=V_ALIGN_AGAIN, anchor='c')

        self.parent.after(UPDATE_TIME, self.process_queue)

    def setup_audio(self):
        data_in = aa.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NONBLOCK, DEVICE)
        data_in.setchannels(2)
        data_in.setrate(SAMPLE_RATE)
        data_in.setformat(FORMAT)

        data_in.setperiodsize(PERIOD)

        score = 0
        running = False

        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            # Sleep a very short time to prevent the thread from locking up
            time.sleep(0.001)

            if GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN):
                self.tilt_event.clear()
                score = 0
                if not running:
                    self.message_L1.configure(text=L1)
                    self.message_L2.configure(text=L2)
                    self.message_score_header.configure(
                        text=HEADER_MESSAGE,
                        fg=TEXT_COLOR_BODY,
                        font=tkFont.Font(
                            TYPEFACE_HEADER,
                            FONT_SIZE_HEADER,
                            WEIGHT_HEADER,
                        ),
                        pady=LINE_HEIGHT_HEADER)
                    self.message_score.configure(
                        text='0.0',
                        fg=TEXT_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,
                        font=tkFont.Font(
                            TYPEFACE_SCORE,
                            FONT_SIZE_SCORE,
                            WEIGHT_SCORE,
                        ),
                        pady=LINE_HEIGHT_SCORE)
                    self.message_score.place(
                        relx=.5,
                        rely=V_ALIGN_SCORE,
                        anchor='c')

                    running = True
                self.queue.put('0.0')
            elif not running:
                # Not running yet, keep waiting
                continue

            # Read data from device
            l, data = data_in.read()
            if l and not self.tilt_event.is_set():
                # catch frame error
                try:
                    max = audioop.max(data, CHANNELS)
                    scaled_max = max // SCALAR

                    if scaled_max <= NOISE_THRESHOLD:
                        # Too quiet, ignore
                        continue

                    score += scaled_max / 10.0

                    if score > TILT_THRESHOLD:
                        self.tilt_event.set()
                        running = False
                    else:
                        self.queue.put(str(score))

                except audioop.error, e:
                    if e.message != "not a whole number of frames":
                        raise e


def main():
    GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    window = None

    try:
        root = tk.Tk()
        queue = Queue.Queue()
        window = Display(root, queue, stop_event)

        # Force the window to the foreground
        root.attributes('-topmost', True)
        if debug:
            root.maxsize(1920, 1200)

        root.mainloop()
    finally:
        stop_event.set()
        if window:
            window.audio_thread.join()
        del window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

There are no error messages when I run the script.
```